# Why does the Tensorflow tf.FIFOQueue close early in the following code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-multithreading

I am trying to implement a queue that has an `enqueue` running in the background and a `dequeue` running in the main thread.

The goal is to run an optimizer in loop that depends on a value stored in a buffer and only changes with each step in the optimization. Here is a simple example to illustrate:

```
VarType = tf.int32

data0 = np.array([1.0])

init = tf.placeholder(VarType, [1])
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=1, shapes=[1], dtypes=VarType)
nq_init = q.enqueue(init)
# I use a Variable intermediary because I will want to access the
# data multiple times, but I do not want the next data point in the
# queue until I initialize the variable again.
data_ = tf.Variable(q.dequeue(), trainable=False, collections=[])

# Notice that data_ is accessed twice, but should be the same
# in a single sess.run
# so "data_ = q.dequeue()" would not be correct
# plus there needs to be access to initial data
data1 = data_ + 1
data2 = data_ * data1
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(q, [q.enqueue(data2)] * 1)
tf.train.add_queue_runner(qr)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    sess.run(nq_init, feed_dict={init:data0})
    # this first initialization works fine
    sess.run(data_.initializer)
    for n in range(10):
        print(sess.run(data2))
        # this second initialization errors out: 
        sess.run(data_.initializer)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

print('Done')
```

This piece of code errors out, with the following error:

"OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_0_fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)"

Why, and how is this fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the "how to fix it" part, but not the why.

It seems that the first enqueue/dequeue must be run before the second enqueue/dequeue is placed in the QUEUE_RUNNERS collection - but with a caveat, we need to run `sess.run(data_.initializer)` twice:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    sess.run(nq_init, feed_dict={init:data0})
    sess.run(data_.initializer)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for n in range(10):
        print(sess.run(data2))
        sess.run(data_.initializer)
        sess.run(data_.initializer)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Output is as expected:

```
[2]; [6]; [42];...
```

Without the two calls I get the following:

```
[2]; [6]; [6]; [42];...
```

I suspect that `q.enqueue` has its own buffer that holds the old `data2`, so it must be called twice. This also fits with the first value not repeating because at that time the second `q.enqueue` is still empty. Not sure how to overcome this one quirk.